# Custom post type multilingual with Polylang

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, polylang

I have this issue that i do not now how to solve. We have a wordpress page that is multilingual thanks to Polylang plugin. Everything works great except custom post type from other plugin. Post created with this custom post type loads content for Base language which is english, but whenever we change the language it stops working. It does not load content

I registered post type like this:

```
register_post_type( 'placement', 
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Placementy' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Placement' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-write-blog'
    )
);
```

I tried, registering post type in my functions.php instead of plugins main file, still the same... Other custom post types are working great and they are registered the same way. I also tried creating template for custom post type in my wordpress theme instead of using the one from plugin, but it also failed... Do not really know why it is not working. Especially when everything else works. Also cleared cache, after changes. Checked changed in developer and local environment. What can cause such behavior?

Comment: what do you mean by "stopped working"? Do you have debug output that you can post here?

Answer (score 2):

in functions.php

```
    add_filter('pll_get_post_types', 'add_cpt_to_pll', 10, 2);
function add_cpt_to_pll($post_types, $hide) {
    if ($hide)
        // hides 'my_cpt' from the list of custom post types in Polylang settings
        unset($post_types['my_cpt']);
    else
        // enables language and translation management for 'my_cpt'
        $post_types['my_cpt'] = 'my_cpt';
    return $post_types;
}
```

for more details 
https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/filter-reference/